# Show total count of Reports per Profile in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have two models, `Report` and `Profile` and Profile is connected to Report as a foreignKey.

In my `admin.py` I want to show each Profile along with the amount(count) of times that the profile has been reported.

Can't get the function to work as I am left with a "type object 'Profile' has no attribute 'total'" Attribute error. Profile model has no 'total', but I have defined it in the function.

**EDIT 1** I know that profile has no attribute total,im just not sure how to create a queryset/function that will allow me to display the number of reports for each profile

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Profile,Report
from django.db.models import Count

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
list_display = ('id', 'birth_date', 'sessions_played','user_report')

def user_report(self, obj):
    total = Report.objects.count()
    amount = Profile.total
    return amount

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)

class ReportAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

list_display = ('report_reason','sent_by', 'session', 'user_reported')
admin.site.register(Report,ReportAdmin)
```

Models are Linked here as an image link,click to view: https://ibb.co/b9YwsH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the Profile model have an attribute called total? Also what is the meaning for the following line in `amount = Profile.total` in user_report method? Basically you are finding the total count of report and then assigning amount with an attribute of Profile model which doesnot exist.

Comment: There is no attribute called total,I know now that I have to create  a queryset to get the reports for each specific profile but not too sure how to do it

Comment: What I was trying or intending to do was give the number of reports,for each specific profile

Comment: In the user report method, the obj you have is the corresponding Profile object. All you need to do now is write a queryset that returns the same. Assuming each report is linked to one user profile, it would be something like this - `return Report.objects.filter(profile=obj).count()`

Comment: Profile is linked to Reports through user_reported and sent_by attributes,where Profile Model is  the foreign key.

`user_reported = models.ForeignKey(
  'Profile',
  on_delete=models.PROTECT,
  blank=False,
  null=False,
  related_name='user_reported_report',
 )

 sent_by = models.ForeignKey(
  'Profile',
  on_delete=models.PROTECT,
  blank=False,
  null=False,
  related_name='sent_by_report',
 )`